Number of vectors of length $n$ over ${A,C,T,G}$ such that there are no $k$ consecutive $A$'s, $k\geq 2$
I have to come up with a recursive solution to the problem in the title. Here is my attempt:
Let $u(n)$ be a function given the number of valid such vectors of length $n$. Assume we have a valid vector of length $n - 1$. There are 2 possibilities:

If the vector ends in $k - 1$ consecutive $A$'s, then the $k$th letter from the end is $C, G$ or $T$. Then there are $3$ options to choose a letter to append at the end, and we end up with $3\cdot 3\cdot u(n - k - 1)$.
If the vectors does not end in $k - 1$ consecutive $A$'s, then at least one of the last $k - 1$ letters is not $A$. The number of possibilities for such words is $4^{k-1} - 1$. There are $4$ options to choose the letter to append at the end, so we end up with $4\cdot (4^{k-1}-1)\cdot u(n - k)$.

Overall, we end up with the following recursive relationship: $$u(n) = 9u(n - k - 1) + (4^k - 4)u(n - k).$$
And for the starting conditions:
$$\forall n<k, u(n) = 4^n \text{ (All vectors satisfy the condition)}$$
$$u(k) = 4^k - 1 \text{ (All vectors but the all  A's vector satisfy the condition)}$$
$$u(k + 1) = 4^{k + 1} - 7 \text{ (All vectors but A...AT, A....AC etc satisfy the condition)}$$
The reason I'm asking this question, is that I wrote python script that uses my formula to calculate the result, as well as calculate it by brute force. For $k = 2$ I end up with correct results, but for $k = 3$ the brute force approach falls short, probably because I'm overcounting somewhere.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Let me say a word is a string consisting of letters $\mathtt{A},\mathtt{T},\mathtt{C},\mathtt{G}$ without $k$ consecutive $\mathtt{A}$s. Let $u_i(n)$ be the number of words that end in exactly $i$ consecutive $\mathtt{A}$s. Then clearly
$$u(n) = \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} u_i(n).$$
We also have the following equations for $i < k$:
\begin{align*}
u_0(n) &= \begin{cases}
3u(n-1) & (n \ge 1) \\
1 & (n = 0), \\
\end{cases} \\
u_i(n) &= \begin{cases}
u_0(n-i) & (n \ge i) \\
0 & (n < i). \\
\end{cases} \\
\end{align*}
These are just statements of the facts that words of length $n$ are words of length $n-1$ together with a non-$\mathtt{A}$, and that words of length $n$ ending in exactly $i$ $\mathtt{A}$s are equinumerous with words of length $n-i$ that don't end in $\mathtt{A}$.
This is enough to compute $u(n)$ recursively as a sum of $k$ terms. We can do a bit better with the power of generating functions: Let $F$ and $F_i$ be the ordinary generating functions of $u$ and $u_i$; that is,
$$F(t) = \sum_{t=0}^\infty u(n) t^n, \qquad
F_i(t) = \sum_{t=0}^\infty u_i(n) t^n.$$
Then the above equations translate to
\begin{align*}
F_0(t) &= 1 + 3t F(t), \\
F_i(t) &= t^i F_0(t).
\end{align*}
Thus
$$F(t) = \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} F_i(t)
= \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} t^i F_0(t)
= \frac{1 - t^k}{1 - t} (1 + 3tF(t))
$$
which has solution
$$F(t) = \frac{1 - t^k}{1 - 4t + 3t^{k+1}}.$$
This gives an easier-to-compute 3-term recurrence
$$u(n) = 4u(n-1) - 3u(n-k-1) + \begin{cases}
1 & (n = 0), \\
-1 & (n = k), \\
0 & (\text{otherwise}) \\
\end{cases}$$
where it is understood that $u(n)=0$ for $n<0$. This could be interpreted as follows: A word of length $n$ can be obtained from a word of length $n-1$ by adding any letter (the $4u(n-1)$ term), except we may not add an $\mathtt{A}$ if the previous word ended in $k-1$ $\mathtt{A}$s. When $n=k$ this means the previous word was all $\mathtt{A}$s, so we subtract $1$; when $n \ge k+1$ the word must have been a word of length $n-k-1$ followed by a non-$\mathtt{A}$ and then $k-1$ $\mathtt{A}$s, so we subtract $3u(n-k-1)$.
In principle, given a fixed $k$ one could find a closed-form expression for $u(n)$, but that would require finding the roots of a degree $k+1$ polynomial.

Fix $k$ and let $A_n$ for $n \geq 0$ be the number of valid strings of length $n$, so it’s the quantity you wish to compute. Then $A_0 = 1$, which accounts for the empty string, and for $n>0$,
$$A_n = \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} A_{n,i},$$
where $A_{n,i}$ is the number of valid strings of length $n$ that end with exactly $i$ A’s, and can be computed recursively: for $0 \leq i < n$,
$$A_{n,i} = 3A_{n-i-1},$$
and $A_{n,n}=[n<k]$ (in other words, if $n<k$, then $A_{n,n} = 1$, and otherwise $A_{n,n} = 0$).

You mean $A_{n,n} = [n < k]$? (and of course the recursive equation is only valid for $i < k$)

Yes, @arkeet, I did. Thanks.
